# Como executar shell script para reiniciar servidor pela aplicação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou precisando executar um shell a partir do rails com uma pequena diferença, eu preciso que o script continue rodando mesmo que o processo servidor(puma) seja morto.

Adicionei um sistema de atualização por dentro da minha applicação, mas preciso reiniciar o servidor para funcionar as alterações. Quando executo o arquivo sh para reiniciar o servidor, ele desliga o server e interrompe a execução do script e consequentemente não inicia novamente o servidor.

Comment: Bem vindo colega. Não é necessário postar em inglês sua pergunta. Traduzi o título, se estiver incorreto por favor altere.

Comment: Junior é muito estranho ter que reiniciar a aplicação para atualizar algo, sendo que a linguagem é interpretada, deveriamos poder buscar essas informações novas em arquivos ou algo do tipo.

Qual é o problema que você está tendo de fato que está tentando solucionar com o restart server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que você rode um script desvinculado do processo que o iniciou, você precisa manda-lo para o segundo plano. Por exemplo se você está rodando:

> sh ./meuscript.sh

basta adicionar & na execução que ele passará a rodar independentemente do processo que o criou, ficando dessa forma:

> sh ./meuscript.sh &

Assim o processo que o criou, pode ser encerrado, sem que ele seja também.